# How to pass a cookies value in a javascript fetch post to Node JS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to pass a cookie value to my Node JS server using javascript fetch post, but everytime I try and read req.body on the server, it is empty.

Comment: Cookies aren't included in the request body. Look for `request.headers.cookie`

Comment: I include the cookie value as the body key

Comment: That's not how cookies work.

Comment: I get the cookie value as a string before the fetch and pass the string in the body

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.